# Don't see a dependency property in the Designer

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties, designer

I have a WPF MyUserControl.
Inside, I defined a dependency property (as by default that does Visual Studio)

```
  Public Property Prop1 As String
    Get
      Return GetValue(Prop1Property).ToString()
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
      SetValue(Prop1Property, value)
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Shared ReadOnly Prop1Property As DependencyProperty = _
                      DependencyProperty.Register("Prop1", _
                      GetType(String), GetType(ctlMyUserControl.MyUserControl), _
                      New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing))
```

I successfully compiled the project, but I don't see in the WPF's control designer my `Prop1`.
Why?

I also defined a "usual" property like

```
Public Property Test1 As String
```

But I don't see it in the designer either. Why?

**EDIT**

I added MyUserControl in a other WPF control, and there I can see that properties. But in the designer of the MyUserControl itself (when I select the root UserControl), that properties are not visible...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to decorate your properties such as :

```
[Category("Configuration")]
```

or

```
[Category("Configuration"), Browsable(true), Description("Title to show")]
```

I think its a normal behavior to not see the props when you are in the designer of the userControl. Why would you want to see them there, as you are only "creating" the usercontrol, and not consuming it.

Comment: it's strange that I can see it in other control's designers (if I add there MyControl), but not in the UserControl's designer itself.

Comment: thats actually pretty normal I believe :D You dont need to see them when you are creating/designing your userControl. You just need them when you consume it.